# Representing a complex Perl data structure containing array references in Config::General

Tags: perl, data-structures, configuration-files

I have the following data structure in Perl code:

```
my $config = {
    'View::Mason' => {
        comp_root     => [
            [ 'teamsite'   => 'root/teamsite' ],
            [ 'components' => 'root/components' ],
        ],
    },
};
```

I'm trying to represent this structure in a [Config::General](http://search.cpan.org/~tlinden/Config-General-2.43/General.pm) configuration file.

So far I have:

```
<View::Mason>
    <comp_root>
        teamsite        root/teamsite
    </comp_root>
    <comp_root>
        components      root/components
    </comp_root>
</View::Mason>
```

Which at least makes the "comp_root" element an array reference, but I can't get it to point to another array reference.

Can this be done in Config::General?

Comment: Hmmm... after digging into it a bit more it seems the answer is "you can't do that with Config::General"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible with Config::General.  For example:

```
use Config::General qw(SaveConfigString);

my $config = {
    'View::Mason' => {
        comp_root     => [
            [ 'teamsite'   => 'root/teamsite' ],
            [ 'components' => 'root/components' ],
        ],
    },
};

print SaveConfigString($config);
```

produces

```
<View::Mason>
    comp_root   ARRAY(0x94ea168)
    comp_root   ARRAY(0x94fbc98)
</View::Mason>
```

If it can't save it, odds are it can't load it.

Here's what I would do:

1. Figure out what I want my config file to look like.
2. Find a module capable of loading a config file like that.  (Possibly making some changes to the format, if it proves too difficult to load.)
3. If the result of step 2 is not suitable for direct use by the rest of my program, write some code to convert what the config reader gives me into what my program wants.

Comment: I'm kind of locked in to Config::General at the moment but sounds like a good approach for the next project. What I might have to do here is some post-processing to merge in multiple config settings into the final data structure the module requires.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

YAML might be an option for you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use YAML::XS qw(Load);

my $config_text = '
View::Mason:
  comp_root:
    -
      - teamsite
      - root/teamsite
    -
      - components
      - root/components
';

my $config = Load($yaml_text);
print Dumper($config);
```

Comment: While YAML can represent any arbitrary Perl data structure, it's not necessarily the most user-friendly config file format.  (Although I have used it for config files that needed to contain complex data structures.)

Comment: <rant>Raw perl is friendlier than YAML; at least whitespace isn't significant</rant>